# Python: Trying to create nested dictionary from CSV File, but getting KeyError

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am currently am trying to create a nested dictionary from a csv file.

The CSV File represents how many people there are for each demographic region. In the nested dictionary each key is a region and the value is another dictionary. The inner dictionary uses the demographic as key and the number of people for its value.

```
Region,American,Asian,Black
midwest,2500,2300,2150
north,1200,2300,2300
south,1211,211,2100
```

Currently have:

```
def load_csv(filename):
data={}
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        fh = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in fh:
            key = row.pop('Region')
            data[key] = row
        return data
```

Expected Output (must convert the numbers from strings to integers):

```
{'west':{'American': 2500, 'ASIAN': 2300, ...}, 'north':{'American': 1200, ..}...}
```

I'm getting stuck when running my code as it is giving me "KeyError: 'Region'"

Comment: This would be so much shorter with pandas [`.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv) and [`.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict) : just **`def load_csv(filename): return pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0).to_dict('index')`** [This just takes the first column as index, no matter what it is; you could also use `index_col='Region'` and it would raise error if `Region` column was missing]

Comment: We are not able to use pandas

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehension to convert string values to integers:

```
import csv

def load_csv(filename):
    data = {}
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        # Your file has 3 invisible characters at the beginning, skip them
        csvfile.seek(3)
        fh = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in fh:
            key = row.pop('Region')
            data[key] = {k: int(v) for k, v in row.items()}  # <- HERE
        return data

data = load_csv('data.csv')
```

Output:

```
>>> data
{'midwest': {'American': 2500, 'Asian': 2300, 'Black': 2150},
 'north': {'American': 1200, 'Asian': 2300, 'Black': 2300},
 'south': {'American': 1211, 'Asian': 211, 'Black': 2100}}
```

**Bonus**: The same operation with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col='Region').T.to_dict()
print(data)

# Output
{'midwest': {'American': 2500, 'Asian': 2300, 'Black': 2150},
 'north': {'American': 1200, 'Asian': 2300, 'Black': 2300},
 'south': {'American': 1211, 'Asian': 211, 'Black': 2100}}
```

Comment: Hi, using first method still getting the KeyError do you know why this could be? It is spelled Region in the file

Comment: As I haven't this problem on your sample, I guess there is something wrong with your file. Can you share it?

Comment: Yes, how do I share it?

Comment: I have attached a picture of the csv file in VSCode

Comment: You can use wetransfer or google drive?

Comment: Yes, do you have your emai;l

Comment: No I cant use pandas

Comment: You have 3 invisible characters before Region (hexadecimal: ef bb bf)

Comment: Do you know the fix for this? how did these come

Comment: I don't know why you have them in your file but I already posted a fix (use seek to move the pointer). I tested and it works with your file.

Comment: Even with the seeker am getting the error

Comment: I tested with your file, I have no error. I really don't understand why! Where do your file come from?

Comment: I downloaded it from my assignment

Comment: do you know if there's a way to do this without DictReader?

Comment: Why do you want a such thing? You can do it with csv.reader but it does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires no imports at all, but will **only work if there are no escaped separators** [i.e., none of the values contain a `,` or newline]:

```py
def load_csv(filename, sep=','):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvlines = csvfile.read().strip().splitlines()
    csvRows = [[v.strip() for v in l.split(sep)] for l in csvlines]
    if not csvRows: return {}
    keys = csvRows[0][1:]
    return {r[0]: dict(zip(keys, r[1:])) for r in csvRows[1:] if r}
```

At the very least, it works [for the csv in your snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXQkT.png), but if your csv contains `,` or newlines at any unexpected positions, this function will no longer be reliable - it would definitely be better to use a module built for reading and parsing csv.